# node.js Обещания, промисы не до конца понимаю

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Вроде и понимаю принцип, а на деле не все гладко.

first.js

```
const getVisa = require('./second.js');
function queryForVisa() {
    console.log('Query processing ...... --------');
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            let allowed = true;
            if(allowed) {
                console.log('Visa is allowed');
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject('The visa is denied');
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
}

queryForVisa()
    .then(getVisa) // этот срабатывает правильно, ждет промиса и тогда начинает выполняться
    .then(function(data) { //этот не дожидается промиса и выполняется
        console.log('last then');
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

second.js

```
const getVisa = function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Visa received');
            let travel = {};
            let visa = {
                country: 'USA'
            }
            travel.visa = visa;
            console.log('getVisa.visa', visa);
            return Promise.resolve(travel);
        }, 2500);
    }

module.exports = getVisa;
```

и лог ответа:

```
Query processing ...... --------
Visa allowed
last then
undefined
Visa received
getVisa.visa { country: 'USA' }
```

понимаю что что то не так с функцией в second а что? Там тоже надо по образу queryForVisa делать new Promise?
Я смотрю чужой код на гитхабе и туториалах, там все просто:

```
function()
.then(function(){...})
.then(function(){...})
```

и внутри ни каких new Promise, return promise.

Comment: Если не возвращать Обещание в `.then`, то все `.then` выполнятся по цепочке, не дожидаясь выполнение предыдущего Обещания.

Comment: @YozhEzhi А разве .then выполняется не только тогда, когда предыдущее действие вернуло resolve? Я думал это работает так: вызываем функцию А, когда функция выполнилась успешно, тогда выполняется .then если нет, то .catch. Узнать выполнилась она или вернула ошибку можно только дождавшись ответа, в чем смысла выполнять последующие .then ?

Comment: если `then` вернуло значение (return или неявный return - undefined), то это и есть `resolve`. то есть последующие `then` сразу могут выполняться.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Так мой то return был только по истечению 2,5сек других там нет, значит вернуть resolve он не мог, по сути он ничего не мог вернуть или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @SergeiR, `then` выполняется **всегда**, если посмотреть определение, то можно увидеть. что эта функция принимает **два** параметра, success и error

Comment: у вас явный return ушел в никуда через 2,5 секунды. а функция `getVisa` вернула `undefined` сразу.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо, я не знал о такой способности функции, это многое объясняет.

Comment: почитайте вот это [про Promise](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) и [про функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немного сократил код. Вытащил функцию из модуля. Но это не должно влиять.

Ваша функция `getVisa` возвращает `undefined` и поэтому все `then` после нее срабатывают без ожидания.

Из функции которую вы передали `then` можно вернуть - **Promise**, **значение** (синхронное) или **исключение**. Задержка - это асинхронная операция - следовательно вам нужно вернуть асинхронное значение - **Promise**.

Я переделал `getVisa` и все работает как ожидается.

```js
function queryForVisa() {
  console.log('Query processing ...... --------');
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      let allowed = true;
      if (allowed) {
        console.log('Visa is allowed');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject('The visa is denied');
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
  return promise;
}

function getVisa() {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Visa received');
      let travel = {};
      let visa = {
        country: 'USA'
      }
      travel.visa = visa;
      console.log('getVisa.visa', visa);
      resolve(travel);
    }, 2500);
  });
  return promise;
}

queryForVisa()
  .then(getVisa)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('last then');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Т.е. там, где ожидается задержка на выполнение всегда нужно создать новый промис? let p = new Promise(). Для меня странно почему она вернула undefined если процесс еще не вополнился.

Comment: Можно не присваивать в переменную, а сразу возвращать `return new Promise()`.

Comment: из функции которую вы передали `then` можно вернуть - **Promise**, значение (синхронное) или исключение. задержка - это асинхронная операция - следовательно вам нужно вернуть асинхронное значение - **Promise**

Comment: @YozhEzhi я знаю - просто хотел сделать их максимально похожими.